# php Help Right Way to Define Classes and Called on different Constructor

Tags: php, class, constructor

Learning the correct way:
create a class and the "constructor" make a call to all classes and extend it to the application.
i have one file to define all class files of type php:

```
<?php
    $APP_PHPCORE_DIR=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/control/class';
    if (!defined('ERRORMANAGER_CLASS'))         define('ERRORMANAGER_CLASS'         ,'class.managererror.php'           );  
    if (!defined('DBMANAGER_CLASS'))            define('DBMANAGER_CLASS'            ,'class.managerdb.php'              );
    if (!defined('USERMANAGER_CLASS'))          define('USERMANAGER_CLASS'          ,'class.manageruser.php'            );  #Clase sobre Administracion de Usuario
    if (!defined('CRIPMANAGER_CLASS'))          define('CRIPMANAGER_CLASS'          ,'class.managercrip.php'            );
    require_once $APP_PHPCORE_DIR . '/' . ERRORMANAGER_CLASS;
    require_once $APP_PHPCORE_DIR . '/' . DBMANAGER_CLASS;
    require_once $APP_PHPCORE_DIR . '/' . USERMANAGER_CLASS;
    require_once $APP_PHPCORE_DIR . '/' . CRIPMANAGER_CLASS;
?>
```

then after having this file I call this in index.php

```
<?php
require_once('config/classlib.php');
?>
```

Later work step by step each file, creating classes that I will use, and design a class libraries, these classes have a constructor where I have to call each of the classes defined in the **"config/classlib.php"**
It is as follows:
Example 1

```
<?php #first File
class Class_Main{
    function __construct(){
        # Contructior de la clase (No usado).
        $this   ->  ERRORMANAGER            =   new Class_ErrorManager();
        $this   ->  DBMANAGER               =   new Class_BDManager();
        $this   ->  USERMANAGER             =   new Class_UserManager();
        $this   ->  CRIPMANAGER             =   new Class_CripManager();
    }
    #bulk of functions...
}
?>
```

Example 2

```
<?php #second File
class Class_ErrorManager{
    function __construct(){
        # Contructior de la clase (No usado).
        $this   ->  DBMANAGER               =   new Class_BDManager();
        $this   ->  USERMANAGER             =   new Class_UserManager();
        $this   ->  CRIPMANAGER             =   new Class_CripManager();
    }
    #bulk of functions...
}
?>
```

Example 3

```
<?php
class Class_UserManager{
    function __construct(){
        # Contructior de la clase (No usado).
        $this   ->  ERRORMANAGER            =   new Class_ErrorManager();
        $this   ->  DBMANAGER               =   new Class_BDManager();
        $this   ->  CRIPMANAGER             =   new Class_CripManager();
    }
    #bulk of functions...
}
?>
```

I'm thinking I'm on the right track, but I'm not sure this making it 100% right, since I have encountered errors:

```
"Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 33554432 bytes)"
```

This by adding a line in the constructor for a class.

```
$this   ->  USERMANAGER             =   new Class_UserManager();
```

**someone has a better idea of how it should do to avoid this, this is just an example, but the fact is that they are more than 16 different classes. and make the call in the constructor is costing me a lot.**

**PS: in the constructor'm making sure not to make calls to the class itself.**

Comment: dependency injection: google it

Comment: What class are you adding '$this->USERMANAGER = new Class_UserManager();' to?

Comment: Class loading should be done via spl_autoload_register. http://php.net/manual/de/function.spl-autoload-register.php . Why do you define constants of class names you are going to load?

Comment: if but the problem is that of the 16 classes, I call this the 10 of them, which makes increasingly consume memory, and not as it should be the code correctly.

Comment: that's just because your class creation is recursive. When you create a `Class_Main` object, you create also a `Class_ErrorManager` instance that create a `Class_UserManager` instance that create a `Class_ErrorManager` instance that create ... and so on.

Comment: One reason more to use spl_autoload_register(). Also I dislike your naming convention. BLOCK_CASE should identify CONSTANTS, CapitalCamelCase or Capital_Snake_Case = Classes (without "class" prefix) and lowerCamelCase or lower_snake_case = variables, functions, properties, methods aso.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone, exactly how can you resolve this problem with an autoloader? OP's need to stop the infinite recursion, and you can do that by creating just one instance.

Comment: At first regard Federico's hint and remove the recursion. You can hold a backreference but don't create new instances recursive. @Federico That wasn't related to your comment.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone, thanks for the appreciation, I try to not only ask things on this page, I try to understand the possible solutions, I'm looking and working in learning more about the auto_load, but I would like to know from you, as would correctly the code, as are 16 classes that are defined and can be implemented more, the example has only 4 classes that are called in the builders.

Comment: For some of your classes you could consider the singleton pattern. That could be the easiest thing at fist, maybe not the best. I like to have one central application class that holds the error class, database aso. and initialises the tree of other instances.

Comment: Try to code an application class that instanciates like `this->error_manager = new Error_Manager(this)`. This way in the constructor you can store a backreference to application which serves the basic managers.

Comment: only need add (this) or ($this);

Comment: $this - I'm used JavaScript last time :)

Comment: with (this) get Notice: Use of undefined constant this - assumed 'this';  with ($this) get the same Fatal error of memory...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107661/discussion-between-walter-nunez-and-quasimodos-clone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with the code as it is right now. You are running out of memory because you have [mutual recursions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion) without [recursion termination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_termination) between your `Class_UserManager` and `Class_ErrorManager` classes.

If you follow the execution of your program you'll notice that when you instantiate the `Class_UserManager` class, the following steps will happen:

- `Class_ErrorManager` is instantiated

  1. `Class_BDManager` is instantiated
  2. `Class_UserManager` is instantiated

     - `Class_ErrorManager` is instantiated

       1. `Class_BDManager` is instantiated
       2. `Class_UserManager` is instantiated

       > Object creation continues until you run out of memory.

You can solve these issue by using Dependency Injection, that is instead of instantiating the classes within the constructor of your class, just take them as a parameter. Objects are passed by reference by default, so you can reduce the memory footprint significantly.

```
<?php
class Class_ErrorManager
{
     public function __construct(Class_BDManager $bdManager, Class_UserManager $usermanager, Class_CripManager $cripManager)
     {
          $this->DBMANAGER = $bdManager;
          // etc...
     }
}
```

Also, you should take a look at the [PHP Coding Style Guide (PSR-2)](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/)

Comment: Hola @AlanChavez estuve mirando tu guía y el tutorial y me gusta la idea pero como hago en el caso de que sean 16 librerías http://pastebin.com/g6XmL2wx

Comment: Implement it i get this error: Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Class_VarManager::__construct() must be an instance of Class_BDManager, none given, called in

Answer (score 0):

Your code modificated: http://pastebin.com/aSSvmA8N

- It creates a standard object which holds all references.
- All classes are instanciated first.
- All instances are initializied with the package of instances in a loop.

The aim is to separate the initialisation from the construction. So you can construct first **all** instances and then initialize them with the hole package of references. To prevent redundant code there is a base class with the init() method.

*Note: It's **not** common to hold all references in every instance. But since this was the guideline, it is a simple solution.*

---

A working demo base construct of a better design

```
<?php

class Application
{
  protected
    $_error_manager = null,
    $_db_manager    = null,
    $_crip_manager  = null
  ;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->_error_manager = new Error_Manager($this, 'some inititialization data');
    $this->_db_manager    = new Db_Manager   ($this, 'some inititialization data');
    // ...
    $this->_error_manager->log('Application initialized.');
  }

  public function get_error_manager()
  {
    return $this->_error_manager;
  }
}

class Base_Class
{
  protected $_application = null;

  public function __construct(Application $application)
  {
    $this->_application = $application;
  }
}

class Error_Manager extends Base_Class
{
  public function __construct(Application $application, $other_argument)
  {
    parent::__construct($application);
    // ...
    $this->log('Error manager initialized.');
  }

  public function log($str)
  {
    echo "$str<br>\n";
  }
}

class Db_Manager extends Base_Class
{
  function __construct(Application $application, $other_argument)
  {
    parent::__construct($application);
    // ...
    $this->_application->get_error_manager()->log('Database manager initialized.');
  }
}

new Application();
?>
```

Or do a dirty thing and give a package of references around:

```
<?php

class Base_Class
{
  protected
    $_application    = null,
    $_error_manager = null,
    $_db_manager    = null,
    $_crip_manager  = null,
    $_another_class = null
  ;

  public function __construct()
  {

  }

  public function init($instances)
  {
    $this->_application     = $instances->application;
    $this->_error_manager   = $instances->error_manager;
    $this->_db_manager      = $instances->db_manager;
    $this->_crip_manager    = $instances->crip_manager;
    $this->_another_class   = $instances->another_class;

    $this->_error_manager->log(get_class($this) . " initialized.");
  }

}

class Application extends Base_Class
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $instances = new stdClass();
    $instances->application   = $this;
    $instances->error_manager = new Error_Manager();
    $instances->db_manager    = new Db_Manager();
    $instances->crip_manager  = new Crip_Manager();
    $instances->another_class = new Another_Class();

    $this->init($instances);
    // after initialized itself we can do:
    $this->_error_manager->init($instances);
    $this->_db_manager   ->init($instances);
    $this->_crip_manager ->init($instances);
    $this->_another_class->init($instances);
  }
}

class Error_Manager extends Base_Class
{
  public function __construct()
  {

  }

  public function log($str)
  {
    echo "$str<br>\n";
  }
}

class Db_Manager extends Base_Class
{
  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }
}

class Crip_Manager extends Base_Class
{
  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }
}

class Another_Class extends Base_Class
{
  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }
}

new Application();
?>
```

Comment: Exact Guideline : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36318350/php-dependency-injection-dinamical-and-packing-or-container